# Onclick set value to input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to change the value form input `onclick`. I've tried it but the input value don't change. Can't find the error. For example when I click on the `choice-label` the `input` should get the `value 5`.

```js
$('.training-niveau .choice-label').click(function() {
  $('#train-niveau').val(this);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="field training-niveau-icon training-niveau">
  <input id="train-niveau" class="train-niveau" name="train-niveau" value="1" type="radio" aria-required="true" autocomplete="off">
  <li class="choice-line thirst-line">
    <div class="choice-wrapper">
      <div class="choice-label">4</div>
      <div class="choice-line"></div>
      <div class="choice-container">
        <div class="choice-inset"></div>
        <div class="choice-bg"></div>
        <div class="choice-bd"></div>
        <div class="choice-overlay"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks to all who helped me :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$('#train-niveau').val(this);`

is setting the value of the input to the jquery object of the label.

use `$('#train-niveau').val($(this).text());`

Comment: deja vu from the previous answer dad.

Answer (score 2):

Just calling `this` only pulls in the [document object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_document.asp).

```js
$('.training-niveau').on('click', '.choice-label', function() {
  console.log($('#train-niveau').val()); //before
  $('#train-niveau').val($(this).text());
  console.log($('#train-niveau').val()); //after
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="field training-niveau-icon training-niveau">
  <input id="train-niveau" class="train-niveau" name="train-niveau" value="1" type="radio" aria-required="true" autocomplete="off">
  <li class="choice-line thirst-line">
    <div class="choice-wrapper">
      <div class="choice-label">4</div>
      <div class="choice-line"></div>
      <div class="choice-container">
        <div class="choice-inset"></div>
        <div class="choice-bg"></div>
        <div class="choice-bd"></div>
        <div class="choice-overlay"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`this` doesn't contain the value, but rather a whole set of functions and values (to verify, do `console.log(this);` If you want the value of this, use this instead:

`$('#train-niveau').val(this.val());` < Which only applies if a value is set to your choice label.

Answer (score 1):

Inside the click function `this` is the normal javascript DOM element, it is not a `jQuery` object. If you want to use `.val()` you need to convert `this` to a javascript variable

```
$('.training-niveau .choice-label').click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $('#train-niveau').val($this.val());  
});
```